# Pipenv: command not found in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipenv

I am getting `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<workspace name>@tmp/durable-9687b918/script.sh: line 1: pipenv: command not found` while running a Jenkins pipeline.

It fails while running the following command:
`pipenv install --dev`

If I run the same command in the server where Jenkins is hosted it works fine. This started failing after I reinstalled Pipenv with below steps:

Uninstalled using: `pip uninstall pipenv`

Installed using: `pip3 install pipenv`, tried `sudo -H pip3 install -U pipenv` as well issue persist.

I had to switch to pip3 because I am using Python 3 now instead of 2.

Comment: Your pipeline executes as a different user than the one you are executing the command as on the server.

Comment: But I installed Pipenv globally. And if I run command whoami in Jenkins pipeline, the output is the same i.e. "root". Any other way to figure out the user for Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

check PATH, you might running python2.x and PIP module installed with pip3. so set your PATH accordingly.